# Principle of least action with transformed time variable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

> I have the following action 
>   $$S=\int L(t,a,\dot{a},\ddot{a}) \ dt,$$
>   $$L=3\ a^2\ \ddot{a}+3\ a\ (\dot{a})^2+3\ a.$$
>   I wish to find the function $a(t)$ which minimizes the action.

I use the Euler-Lagrange equation: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta a}&=&\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{a}} \\
&=& 6\ a\ \ddot{a} + 3\ (\dot{a})^2 + 3 - \frac{d}{dt}(6\ a\ \dot{a}) \\
&=& 6\ a\ \ddot{a} + 3\ (\dot{a})^2 + 3 - (6\ (\dot{a})^2+6\ a\ \ddot{a}) \\
&=& -3\ (\dot{a})^2 + 3 \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
$$a(t)=t.$$

If I change the time variable to $\eta$ where $d\eta=dt/a$ then the above solution is given by
$$\int d\eta = \int \frac{dt}{t}$$
$$\eta = \log t$$
$$e^\eta=t$$
$$a(\eta)=e^\eta.$$

I should be able to derive the solution in terms of $\eta$ directly by varying the action expressed in terms of $\eta$. In order to derive such an expression I need to be able to convert derivatives of $a$ in terms of time $t$, $\dot{a}$, into derivatives of $a$ in terms of time $\eta$, $a'$.
$$\dot{a}=\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{d\eta}{dt}\frac{da}{d\eta}=\frac{da/d\eta}{a}=\frac{a'}{a},$$
$$\ddot{a}=\frac{d\dot{a}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(a'a^{-1})=\frac{1}{a}\frac{d}{d\eta}(a' a^{-1})=\frac{1}{a}(a''a^{-1}-a'a^{-2}a')=\frac{a''}{a^2}-\frac{(a')^2}{a^3}.$$

Therefore the Lagrangian $L$ in the new time variable $\eta$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
L &=& 3\ a^2\ \ddot{a}+3\ a\ (\dot{a})^2+3\ a \\
&=&  3\ a^2 \ \Big(\frac{a''}{a^2} - \frac{(a')^2}{a^3}\Big)+3\ a\ \Big(\frac{a'}{a}\Big)^2+3\ a \\
&=& 3\ a'' + 3\ a.
\end{eqnarray}
The action $S$ is then given by
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& \int L(t,a,\dot{a},\ddot{a}) \ dt \\
&=& \int L(\eta,a,a'')\ a\ d\eta \\
&=& \int (3\ a \ a'' + 3\ a^2)\ d\eta
\end{eqnarray}
I now use the Principle of least action with the new time variable $\eta$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta a}&=&\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}-\frac{d}{d\eta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial a'} \\
&=& 3\ a'' + 6\ a \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Thus I get the equation
$$a''=-2\ a$$
I was expecting the equation
$$a''=a$$
which has the solution
$$a(\eta)=e^\eta.$$

What's gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a double time-derivative as in $\ddot a$, the correct Euler-Lagrange equation is 
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot a}+\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot a}=0\, .
$$
The generalization to higher order derivatives is called (in some texts) the Euler operator (although this is not unique).

A very good reference for this is Peter Olver's
*Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)* by Springer.